# MVC5 project produces an infinite loop to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-10, returnurl

I have a MVC website that uses form based authentication and I am using it in conjunction with IIS-10. When I deploy the site and attempt to access the site I get a massively malformed returnURL which results in a 404, an example of which is show below.

> http://MyWebSite:8080/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin% ..... all the way up to 2,075 characters.

When I run the site in debug or release mode on Visual Studio 2017 everthing thing works fine. The Account controller has a [AllowAnonymous] decorator added

Taking a look in the IIS log, I see that after the initial request at total of 23 302 requests are made in which the return URL is concatenated until a 404 is encountered. Here are the first few log entries

> 2018-01-31 15:58:18 10.153.60.112 GET /Account/Index - 8080 - 192.168.5.158 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 3
>
> 2018-01-31 15:58:18 10.153.60.112 GET /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FIndex 8080 - 192.168.5.158 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 3
>
> 2018-01-31 15:58:18 10.153.60.112 GET /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FIndex 8080 - 192.168.5.158 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 3
>
> 2018-01-31 15:58:18 10.153.60.112 GET /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FIndex 8080 - 192.168.5.158 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 4
>
> 2018-01-31 15:58:18 10.153.60.112 GET /Account/Login ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FIndex 8080 - 192.168.5.158 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 302 0 0 3

Any ideas?

## UPDATE

Fixed the problem thanks to @stephen.vakil in comments below - once I enabled **Anonymous Authentication** in addition to **Forms Authentication** in IIS, every thing worked as expected.

Comment: This looks like an authentication URL that got reposted to the login page 100 times. Looks like your code redirects to the *wrong* login URL. Post your code

Comment: Create a new MVC project with forms authentication and check how authentication is configured, especially the LoginPath in `Startup.Auth.cs`. How does your code differ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  For test purposes, I'm using an unaltered forms based authentication ASP.Net Web Application in VS2017. After originally encountering the problem and being at a loss, I went back to the basic project. FYI, the LoginPath is set to /Account/Login

Comment: Do you have a deny on anonymous in your web.config?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes I did, changing that to enabled solved the problem. Thanks for your input.